# Behaviour of String.split for empty strings

Tags: kotlin

Consider this pattern of assertions:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val list = listOf("one", "two", "three")
    assertEquals(list.subList(0, 3), list.subList(0, 3).joinToString(" ").split(" "))
    assertEquals(list.subList(0, 2), list.subList(0, 2).joinToString(" ").split(" "))
    assertEquals(list.subList(0, 1), list.subList(0, 1).joinToString(" ").split(" "))
    assertEquals(list.subList(0, 0), list.subList(0, 0).joinToString(" ").split(" "))
}
```

All lines follow a pattern of descending list size. All assertions pass, except, somewhat inconsistently, the last one. This is because `"".split(" ")` is not the expected empty list, but instead it's a one-element list containing the empty string.

Is there another way of calling `split`, or another function, that behaves the way I was expecting as described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a slight variation on lukas.j's answer, I think it's a little more readable using `takeIf()`:

```
"".split(" ").takeIf{ it.size > 1 || it[0].isNotEmpty() } ?: emptyList()
```

And of course you can wrap that in a function, e.g.:

```
fun String.mySplit(separator: String)
    = split(separator)
    .takeIf{ it.size > 1 || it[0].isNotEmpty() }
    ?: emptyList()
```

(That example is an extension function, so you can call it in a similar way to `split()`, e.g. `"".mySplit(" ")`)

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the list returned by split has a size of 1 and the sole element is an empty string, and then return an empty list:

```
val text = "".split(" ").let { if (it.size == 1 && it[0].isEmpty()) emptyList() else it }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your first examples are all lists of strings to begin with (I don't mean `List<String>`, just what they contain - they got some strings in 'em), so by joining them into a string and splitting that back out into a list of strings, you end up with the same thing you started with

Whereas with the empty list, with no string in it, by calling `joinToString` you're creating one. And `split` works on a string and always returns a list of them - which is what you'd expect, right? `"hello".split(" ")` shouldn't return an empty list just because there's no space to split on, so neither should `"".split(" ")` - you always just get the original string you called it on

So the whole `joinToString -> split` pipeline produces a list with at least one string in it, which is fine when you're starting with a list of strings, but not if you're starting with an empty list - it's not inconsistent exactly, the logic just falls down for that edge case. If this is for some kind of processing function (like processing arbitrary `List<String>`s that might be empty) I'd consider handling that edge case explicitly:

```
fun List<String>.doThing() =
    if (isEmpty()) emptyList() // or just 'this' if that works for you
    else joinToString(" ").split(" ")
```

or whatever you're up to!